# confused about using projection of vector in ol3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am confused about using projection of vector.

Should  source of data projection be same as vector projection for ol3.
or 
ol3 vector transformes source data to target projection.

Is following code correct as source in "EPSG:4326" target in "EPSG:3857"
   source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                       url: './resources/js/diriFay4326.geojson',
                       projection: 'EPSG:3857'
                       }) ,

I will appreciate if you answer

regards

Comment: At first glance, it seems fine.  Is it working for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right this is currently the way to get openlayers 3 to transform your GeoJSON features.